# Mobile app ionic stopped working after expired SSL certificate and has been changed

Tags: android, ios, cordova, ssl, ionic-framework

My app developed with `Ionic 1.7` and `Cordova 6.0.0`.
It is working properly on NodeJs server with `SSL certificate Class 1` served by `apache`.
When the certificate has expired, I changed the certificate (with another Class 1 certificate with the same CA), the app stopped working.

The notes in the `HTTPS response` (debugged with Charles Web Proxy), say: `SSL Proxying not enabled for this host: enable in Proxy Settings, SSL locations`

I have the same problem with both the app compiled for iOS and Android

the domain is : https://api.tickete.it

Comment: can you provide, if any, the log that you receive on the device?
because that message sounds like a Charles problem

Comment: @Jay did you get this figured out yet? We ran into exactly the same problem today.

Comment: @MrTechie what's yours CA ?

Comment: It looks I have a similar problem since yesterday. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35429324/ionic-based-buttons-cannot-be-clicked-anymore.

Comment: @MrTechie i resolved the problem !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that Apache needs the `SSLCertificateChainFile`to solve app's problems.

To create the CA bundle, you must process as follow (for startSSL Class1):

```
   # wget https://www.startssl.com/certs/ca.crt
   # wget https://www.startssl.com/certs/sca.server1.crt
   # cat sca.server1.crt ca.crt > bundle.pem
```

Now you need to set the SSLCertificateChainFile into `apache2` config file:

```
    #   Server Certificate Chain:
    #   Point SSLCertificateChainFile at a file containing the
    #   concatenation of PEM encoded CA certificates which form the
    #   certificate chain for the server certificate. Alternatively
    #   the referenced file can be the same as SSLCertificateFile
    #   when the CA certificates are directly appended to the server
    #   certificate for convinience.
        SSLCertificateChainFile /your/path/bundle.pem
```

The `bundle.em` has this structure:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE----- 
 blablabla
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
blablabla
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```